# ffmpeg licensing is not clear

Tags: licensing, ffmpeg

its not directly programming question 
but i need to implement ffmpeg functionality in my application that is commercial.
what is my restrictions when using this lib/app ? 
i was confused from reading there web page .

Answer (score 2):

*"FFmpeg is free software and is licensed under the LGPL or GPL depending on your choice of configuration options."* from the homepage.

The mini-FAQ at http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html should probably answer your questions. Do you have a specific part of it you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html

That sums up all relevant information quite nicely.

I would say that if you want to incorporate FFmpeg into your commercial application, you should consult a lawyer who is familiar with the laws and regulations in your area and the area in which you wish to distribute your application.

Comment: Alternately, just contact the library author and ask.  Considerably cheaper than a lawyer (assuming they answer), and you probably get a better answer -- generally, if the program author is happy with what you're doing, you'll be okay regardless of whether the letter of the license allows it (though consult your lawyer if you're concerned about them changing their mind, certainly!), whereas if they're not happy it can be an unpleasant situation regardless of what the license says.

Comment: Addendum: That's with regard to the interaction between you and the library author. Having seen that mini-FAQ, I would say that it sounds like talking to a lawyer about the potential third-party patent issues sounds wise.